# How can i apply a single test case to all the pages of the website using selenium and junit?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, junit4

I have a task in hand to test a website using selenium.
I have to check all the broken links and images on all the pages of the website.
I am using **selenium with junit.**
I have written two test cases to test broken links and images on **HomePage** of my website and the testcases are working fine.
Now i want to apply these test cases to all the pages of the website but i am short of ideas as i am completely new to selenium and junit.
As far as i know i cannot control the invocation of junit tests or else i was thinking of writing a function in which ill iterate to all the webpages in the browser and invoke tests for each webpage but that is not going to work i believe. Any ideas are welcomed but i cant change my tools, I need suggestions that will work for selenium in java.

Comment: Presumably your existing test works against a url.  You just need to get urls for your site with a spidering process or from a site map and add a loop or similar to your program.  Without actual code it's difficult to give a more specific answer

Answer (score 2):

You can easily loop your test like this:

```
public class SeleniumLoop {
    // make your list of urls, can be static for example:

    private static List<String> urls;

    static {
        urls = new ArrayList<>();
        urls.add("http://www.test/1");
        urls.add("http://www.test/2");
        urls.add("http://www.test/3");
    }

    // Java 8 style
    @Test
    public void testAllUrls() {
        urls.stream().forEach(url -> {
            yourTest(url);
        });
    }

    private void yourTest(String url) {
        // your selenium webbdriver
        driver.get(url);
        // your test here
    }
}
```

Please note that it's just a generic - non tested example. It just shows that you can easily loop your Junit tests.

Comment: Hi @Richard, thanks for the wonderful answer there, I was thinking of something similar was just not sure about it. There is just one little issue, In the above code i have to put all the url  manually. Is there anyway to automate these task. I googled it and i found a blog which instructs on how to create a crawler and how can i get all my links of website in a text file.I can use that but is there any simpler way to do this. Any inbuilt api of selenium?

Comment: Hi, I don't think there is a ready solution for it in Selenium. Anyway there's a plenty of Java crawlers if you can use one in your project: http://java-source.net/open-source/crawlers

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the same test cases for a few different variables (such as different URLs) then you can try [JUnit Parameters](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_parameterized_test.htm):

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ParameterDemo {
    protected static final String[] URLS = {"http://url1.com", "http://url2.com", "http://url3.com"};

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        Collection<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        for (String i : URLS) {
            data.add(new String[] {i});
        }
        return data;
    }
    @Parameter public String url;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        driver.get(url);
        //perform test actions
    }
}
```